# Thunderbird calendar events don't have clickable URLs turned on

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, url

Is there a way to make my T-bird calendars have "live" (clickable) URLs in them? Like many others, my calendar now has lots of Zoom & webex meetings. It's a nuisance to open the event, copy the URL, open it in FireFox... Much easier to just click the URL, as I can when using my online mail client or MSFT's Outlook client.

Comment: There is a bug open for this issue, since 11 years: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=553132

Comment: 11 years? That's awful. WHat does it take to get this elevated? I've read through the bugzilla, and much work has been done, but nobody has ever finished this.

Answer (score 2):

A bypass solution is to add the URL in the "location" field of the event. In that case, when you get the event notification (e.g. 1 minute before the meeting starts) the URL in the location field appears clickable.

[image: event notification with URL in the location field]

This doesn't fully reply to your request, since many events come as invitations from other people, and in that case the URL is part of the description and is not clickable. I think the only solution to that is to highlight the importance of the [older bug in in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=553132) and [this newer one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697370) and hope it gets implemented soo.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a clickable link in the Attachments tab for the event.